# UIAlertController sometimes prevents UIRefreshControl to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using `UIRefreshControl` on my tableview to update items. And the end, I show a `UIAlertController` to inform the user that the update was complete, and how many items were updated. Pretty straightforward, and it works fine for one thing.  If I pull to refresh several times in a row, sometimes the refresh control is not dismissed, even after dismissing the alert. I need to swipe up the table to make it go away.

This is the code I use, all UI stuff is nicely done on the main thread:

```
    if(refreshControl.refreshing) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self refreshItems];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [refreshControl endRefreshing];
                [self.tableView reload];
                [self showUpdateInfo];                     
            });
        });
    }
```

Any idea what could cause this?

EDIT: This is how I create the refresh control in code (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.attributedTitle   = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Checking for updates…"];
[refreshControl addTarget: self
                   action: @selector(refreshOutdatedItems)
         forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Comment: Are you creating the UIRefreshControl in code or using the TableViewController property?

Comment: See the edit in my question.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the issue.  Your code seems to work as expected.  BTW you have dispach_sync  that actually crashed on me.  Is that on purpose or it should be dispatch_async ?

Comment: That's a typo, fixed.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue in the simulator.  If I quickly refresh the table twice the UIAlertController shows but the tableview never goes back up and gets stuck in the middle and it show the refreshcontroller still spinning.  I guess the tableview doesn't have enough time to scroll up and freezes while showing the alertcontroller.  Might have to setup some small timer to give the tableview chance to go backup.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I believe it really has to do with the tableView not scrolling back up before the UIAlertController is presented.  I tried to set the delay for showUpdateInfo method and that seems to worked.  I guess when the user only pulls once it will take half a second to show the UIAlertController check if that helps.
Here is my code

```
- (void)refreshOutdatedItems
{
    NSLog(@"refresh");

    if (self.refreshControl.refreshing) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            for (double i = 0 ; i < 100000000; i++){

            };

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
                [self performSelector:@selector(showUpdateInfo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if helps.

Comment: Great! It's working even a bit smoother (in my taste) with shorter delay (0.1sec).

Comment: I put it back at 0.5 sec, at 0.1 sec it still happens.

Comment: I guess depends how far down the table view is when the data refresh is completed.   Maybe there is a way to detect when tableview ends animating but might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: I'm happy with it now, so I will leave it at 0.5 sec :)

Comment: Great!  Happy coding!

Comment: Another solution I just tried is to put the `endRefreshing` call inside the `UIAlertAction` handler that is called when the user dismisses the alert. But it doesn't look that nice, I think.

Comment: @Koen I was actually thinking about that but I agree feels out of place to put endrefreshing in the handler

Comment: Hmm, so even with both in place, the call in the handler as a backup so to speak, the `refreshControl` is occasionally not dismissed. It sometimes happens when you really pull far down, and hold until the alert shows up. And then it doesn't disappear on dismissing, even with `endRefreshing` in the handler. So something else could be going on as well.

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with animation and it all being executed in the main queue and then alert shows and blocks the execution of hiding the refresh control and tableview scrolling up

Comment: Yeah, if I present the alert without animation, it doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote you, but this is not good code.  Your for loop will probably get optimised out.  Use a dispatch.after instead.

Comment: @Yan please see this answer https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42508 there are two problems. 1. The empty for loop is wasting CPU power and 2. the for loop may get optimised out (as Brett also mentioned). If you have to delay, I agree with Brett, rather use dispatch.after

Answer (score 8):

Delaying by an arbitrary time is not a very clean solution. Implementing the delay by counting up a double to 10 million also is a bit of a hack in my opinion.

What I ended up doing instead is similar to this pseudo-Swift:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(...)
present(alert, animated: true) {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

It delays the call to endRefreshing() until the alert is presented.

My actual code using Swift 3 and PromiseKit looks more like this:

```
@IBAction func onRefresh() {
    Repository.getNewData().then { data in
        self.data = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }.recover { error in
        // Return a promise to make sure endRefreshing isn't called until the alert is presented.
        return self.presentErrorAlert(message: "Some user-friendly message")
    }.always {
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}

private func presentErrorAlert(message: String) -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise<Void> { fulfill, _ in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true) {
            fulfill()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer—delaying by an arbitrary amount is a hack.

Comment: Please rewrite answer in Objective C without reactive code, so I can try this out.

Answer (score 5):

Those works for me:

```
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    -- show alert than --
```

Comment: this seems like a dirty hack but works better than the other solutions, since the alert view controller doesn't necessarily need to be triggered from the refresh itself but could be from another asynchronous action

Answer (score 3):

Simply reset the content offset of table view:

```
- (void)endRefreshControl {
     [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

When your task completes, call    `[self endRefreshControl];`
rather than       `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode. Even Johan Levin's solution sometimes seems to hang in Xcode 9.2.

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's a workaround: Don't use the UIAlertController. Just place the text you had in UIAlertController into the UIRefreshControl like so:

```
refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to reload all reminders", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 182.0/255.0, blue: 8.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension to your view controller:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(withTitle title: String, andMessage message: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: L10n.General.ok, style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

then use the following code to show the alert. In the completion block of the alert the refresh control is stopped and will fade out smoothly.

```
showAlert(withTitle: "My Title", andMessage: "There was an error", completion: { 
      refreshControl.endRefreshing() 
 })
```